# Remove redundant tags inside <TABLE> tag from XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, bi-publisher

I got below data in input.xml file, It contains few of the `<I>` tags outside of `<TD>` tags which are creating a problem in BI report generation. Please help with XSLT code to tidy this XML. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
<TABLE border="1" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <TBODY>
        <TR></TR>
        <TR>
            <TD vAlign="top" width="402">
                <P>
                    <B>Column Heading here </B>
                </P>
            </TD>
            <TD vAlign="top" width="234">
                <P>
                    <B>Another Heading</B>
                </P>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD vAlign="top" width="402">
                <P>
                    <I>
                        Item for discount
                        <I></I>
                    </I>
                </P>
                <I>
                    <I></I>
                </I>
            </TD>
            <I>
                <I>
                    <TD vAlign="top" width="234">
                        <P align="center">
                            <I>%</I>
                        </P>
                        <I>
                            <I></I>
                        </I>
                    </TD>
                    <I>
                        <I></I>
                    </I>
                </I>
            </I>
        </TR>
        <I>
            <I>
                <I>
                    <I>
                        <TR>
                            <TD vAlign="top" width="402">
                                <P>
                                    <I>
                                        Item for discount
                                        <I></I>
                                    </I>
                                </P>
                                <I>
                                    <I></I>
                                </I>
                            </TD>
                            <I>
                                <I>
                                    <TD vAlign="top" width="234">
                                        <I>
                                            <P align="center">
                                                <I>%</I>
                                            </P>
                                        </I>
                                        <I>
                                            <I></I>
                                        </I>
                                    </TD>
                                    <I>
                                        <I></I>
                                    </I>
                                </I>
                            </I>
                        </TR>
                        <I>
                            <I>
                                <I>
                                    <I></I>
                                </I>
                            </I>
                        </I>
                    </I>
                </I>
            </I>
        </I>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Expected output :(** tags between ** should get removed)

```
<TABLE border="1" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <TBODY>
        <TR></TR>
        <TR>
            <TD vAlign="top" width="402">
                <P>
                    <B>Column Heading here </B>
                </P>
            </TD>
            <TD vAlign="top" width="234">
                <P>
                    <B>Another Heading</B>
                </P>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD vAlign="top" width="402">
                <P>
                    <I>
                        Item for discount
                        <I></I>
                    </I>
                </P>
                <I>
                    <I></I>
                </I>
            </TD>
            **
            <I>
                <I>
                    **
                    <TD vAlign="top" width="234">
                        <P align="center">
                            <I>%</I>
                        </P>
                        <I>
                            <I></I>
                        </I>
                    </TD>
                    **
                    <I>
                        <I></I>
                    </I>
                </I>
            </I>
            **
        </TR>
        **
        <I>
            <I>
                <I>
                    <I>
                        **
                        <TR>
                            <TD vAlign="top" width="402">
                                <P>
                                    <I>
                                        Item for discount
                                        <I></I>
                                    </I>
                                </P>
                                <I>
                                    <I></I>
                                </I>
                            </TD>
                            **
                            <I>
                                <I>
                                    **
                                    <TD vAlign="top" width="234">
                                        <I>
                                            <P align="center">
                                                <I>%</I>
                                            </P>
                                        </I>
                                        <I>
                                            <I></I>
                                        </I>
                                    </TD>
                                    **
                                    <I>
                                        <I></I>
                                    </I>
                                </I>
                            </I>
                            **
                        </TR>
                        **
                        <I>
                            <I>
                                <I>
                                    <I></I>
                                </I>
                            </I>
                        </I>
                    </I>
                </I>
            </I>
        </I>
        **
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a template that matches `<I>` elements that have `<TD>` siblings:

```
<xsl:template match="I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD ]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Since `<xsl:apply-templates>` default behavior is to only copy textual nodes, if, as in the sample you provided, the `<I>` elements are empty, then it will not copy them to the output.

If you want it to be recursive you can add the children to the match:

```
<xsl:template match="I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD | ancestor::I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD] ]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Update:
If you only want to remove the `<I>` elements that have `<TD>` siblings and its `<I>` children then you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD | parent::I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD] ]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

This is actually very basic Xpath. If you're often dealing with this kind of issue, I strongly recommend you to take one hour or two to read something about Xpath. It's really worth it.

Comment: Sorry, the sample you provided for the output is not well formatted Xml (even with the star removed). I can't indent it and it's very difficult to read. Could you send it again?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
With this code, I am loosing next TD tag also with the text as well.
Like Input:
<TABLE><TR><TD vAlign="top" width="402"><P><I>[insert named product]<I></I> </I></P><I><I></I></I></TD><I><I><TD vAlign="top" width="234"><P align="center"><I>%</I></P><I><I></I></I></TD><I><I></I></I></I></I></TR></TABLE>

Coming Output :
<TABLE>
<TR><TD vAlign="top" width="402">
         <P>
            <I>[insert named product]<I/> </I>
         </P>
         <I><I/>
         </I>
      </TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>

Comment: Sorry, Here it is :
Input XML:
<TABLE>
<TR><TD vAlign="top" width="402"><P><I>[insert named product]<I></I> </I></P><I><I></I></I></TD><I><I><TD vAlign="top" width="234"><P align="center"><I>%</I></P><I><I></I></I></TD><I><I></I></I></I></I></TR>
</TABLE>

Expected Output:
<TABLE>
<TR><TD vAlign="top" width="402"><P><I>[insert named product]<I></I> </I></P><I><I></I></I></TD>     <TD vAlign="top" width="234"><P align="center"><I>%
</I></P><I><I></I></I></TD>                      </TR>
</TABLE>

Comment: Here's the output I get, it looks like what you asked, no? <TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <P>
                <I>[insert named product]<I/>
                </I>
            </P>
            <I>
                <I/>
            </I>
        </TD>
        
            <TD>
         <P>%</P>
      </TD>‌​
        
    </TR>
</TABLE>

Comment: Thanks, Yes that absolutely what i asked for, but why it's not coming for me **Input:**
<TABLE>
<TR><TD><P><I>[insert named product]<I></I> </I></P><I><I></I></I></TD><I><I><TD ><P><I>%</I></P><I><I></I></I></TD><I><I></I></I></I></I></TR>
</TABLE>
**Output**
<TABLE><TR>
      <TD><P><I>[insert named product]<I/> </I></P>
         <I><I/></I>
      </TD>
   **next TD is removed**
   </TR>
</TABLE>
XSLT : <xsl:template match="I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD | parent::I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD] ]"/>

Sorry I am very new to XSL so I may be silly

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD | parent::I[preceding-sibling::TD | following-sibling::TD] ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I think there's maybe another issue within your stylesheet. Please accept the answer and ask another question with your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Answers.
created a more generic solution:
It will remove all the empty tags between

```html
</TD> $<TD> and </TR> $ </TBODY>
```

, 
$ - represents any empty tag.

```
<xsl:template match="//*[ancestor::TR and not(ancestor::TD) and not(self::TD)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
```

```
<xsl:template match="//*[ancestor::TBODY and not(ancestor::TR) and not(self::TR)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
```